# Plone5: Is there a handler for password change

Tags: plone

How do one find out if a plone user has changed/reset his password?
Is there an event that is fired?

While debugging I learned that PlonePAS may be a solution. Therefore a IUserManagement implementer has to be created and registered.

Is this the way to go? Are there alternatives?

Any help appreciated

Volker

Comment: Tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i think that's a possible way, when i look in the PlonePAS Event code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `Products.PluggableAuthService.interfaces.events.ICredentialsUpdatedEvent`